# create a variable with dynamic data type in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a way to declare a variable in a plpgsql function, which data type is set on a parameter? 
For example:

```
create or replace function test(datatype text)<br> returns void as $$
declare
  data datatype;  -- data type is stored in the text string, for example int
begin
  raise notice '%', (select pg_typeof(data));
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

In other words, i am trying to write a function, and inside that function i need a variable, and that variable data type must be defined in another input parameter.
Any ideas?
Bests regards

Answer (score 5):

There is one way - you can use [polymorphic parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html). The PLpgSQL is limitted in this area - the language is designed as very static - so you can do some dynamic work, but usually this work is hard (sometimes it is signal of unhappy design). The variable should be declared outside as function argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(anyelement)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '<<%>>', pg_typeof($1);
END;
$function$

postgres=# SELECT foo(NULL::int), foo(NULL::text);
NOTICE:  <<integer>>
NOTICE:  <<text>>
┌─────┬─────┐
│ foo │ foo │
╞═════╪═════╡
│     │     │
└─────┴─────┘
(1 row)
```

The C language - C functions supports full environment and you can do there much more than in PLpgSQL. PLpgSQL is designed for static strict business processes - where using too dynamic code is usually wrong.